# jQuery template: Creating a conditional statement with AND operators

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

This works:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{if (ON) }} checked {{/if}} id="cbCentral" />
```

This doesn't work:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{if (ON && QC) }} checked {{/if}} id="cbCentral" />
```

It seems && cannot be used to represent an AND operator. How can I express an AND operator?
ON and QC are type boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
{{if ON && QC}}checked{{/if}}
```

I threw together a simple test using AND in an `{{if}}` here: http://jsfiddle.net/Encosia/vNXV5/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the property doesn't exist.  So, for example, http://jsfiddle.net/ruprict/YtHHK/ raises an error.  I would think testing for the existence of a property and then doing stuff if it's there would be a common need.