# Jquery template if xx && if yy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

Is there a

```
{{if something && if something_else}}lalala{{/if}}
```

in Jquery templates? I can't get it to work.

This works:

```
{{if something}}{{if something_else}}lalala{{/if}}{{/if}}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery template: Creating a conditional statement with AND operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332040/jquery-template-creating-a-conditional-statement-with-and-operators)

Answer (score 1):

```
{{if something && something}}lalala{{/if}}
```

this should work

Comment: No, it complains "Uncaught ReferenceError: something_else is not defined" since the second one is missing from the json response.

Comment: i dont understand then the problem that somthing_else value is not passing in the json responce not in the condition form

Comment: Maybe I've should have said that I want to test if the variables exist. {{if x!=undefined && y!=undefined}}

Comment: `{{if  $.type(x)!=undefined && $.type(y)!=undefined}} `
or
`{{if  jQuery.type(x)!=undefined && jQuery.type(y)!=undefined}}`